# How do i make a neverending loop for "next" oder "prev" buttons [php/jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how do i make a neverending loop for "next" oder "prev" buttons?
For example: if there are 7 recordsets and the user presses the "next" or "prev" buttons so the recordsets it wouldn't stop by reaching recordset 0 or 7.

I have the following code and tried many ways to solve them:

```
var jsonData = '
[
  {"count":1,"file":"fb305d5921e6ef7336c4ce3750b7e0a8.jpg"},  
  {"count":2,"file":"c2fce6d2d0af805b2d21159be7e0e60b.jpg"},
  {"count":3,"file":"9c49190d7c152a3891ac991ebb512885.jpg"},
  {"count":4,"file":"529eae9e455b24da93f4696f10eda3c0.jpg"},
  {"count":5,"file":"164e16bf35d331134e872be0ccd1d2aa.jpg"},
  {"count":6,"file":"f34a37b9117026139ddc297da0df2cbc.jpg"},
  {"count":7,"file":"ebafad68984e409a409e9eec86f6c7c9.jpg"}
]';

function getId(file) {
    for(var f in jsonData) {
       if(jsonData[f].file == file)
         return jsonData[f].count;
    }
}

var ActualCounter = getId("fb305d5921e6ef7336c4ce3750b7e0a8.jpg");
var TotalPics = '7';

$('.PicNext').click(function() {
    if(ActualCounter == TotalPics) return false; 
    var SetNext = ActualCounter++;
    $('#ShowPicture').attr('src', '/Media/'+ jsonData[SetNext].file);
});

$('.PicPrev').click(function() {
    if(ActualCounter == 1) return false; 
    var SetPrev = ActualCounter--;
    $('#ShowPicture').attr('src', '/Media/'+ jsonData[SetPrev].file);
});
});
```

So for the .PicNext i tried also this:

```
$('.PicNext').click(function() {
   if(ActualCounter == TotalPics) { var SetNext = 0; } else {
   var SetNext = ActualCounter++; }
   $('#ShowPicture').attr('src', '/Media/'+ jsonData[SetNext].file);
});
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a pretty complicated approach. But anyways, your problem may be that you're not updating `ActualCounter` when you do `var SetNext = 0`. Since you're not updating it, the picture will get stuck on 0 because `ActualCounter == TotalPics` is always true.

But you don't really need this complicated approach. Just keep a regular array index (from 0 to n-1) and use the remainder/modulus operator when the index changes:

```
 index = (index + jsonData.length) % jsonData.length;
```

### Update

A version using the modulo approach:

```
var jsonData = [
  "fb305d5921e6ef7336c4ce3750b7e0a8.jpg"
  "c2fce6d2d0af805b2d21159be7e0e60b.jpg",
  "9c49190d7c152a3891ac991ebb512885.jpg",
  "529eae9e455b24da93f4696f10eda3c0.jpg",
  "164e16bf35d331134e872be0ccd1d2aa.jpg",
  "f34a37b9117026139ddc297da0df2cbc.jpg",
  "ebafad68984e409a409e9eec86f6c7c9.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

$('.PicNext').click(function() {
    index += 1;
    index = (index + jsonData.length) % jsonData.length;
    $('#ShowPicture').attr('src', '/Media/'+ jsonData[index]);
});

$('.PicPrev').click(function() {
    index -= 1;
    index = (index + jsonData.length) % jsonData.length;
    $('#ShowPicture').attr('src', '/Media/'+ jsonData[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but how i do apply that modulo in my example?

Comment: you don't need it in your example. just make sure `ActualCounter` is being updated when you do `SetNext = 0`. if you want to use the modulo approach (which is a lot easier), just do `index++`, followed by that modulo assignment.

Comment: I added an example using the modulo approach. It might not work exactly but it shows how straightforwardly it can be done. By the way this is called "cyclic array indexing".